# Something like a picture/content manager that's easy to use

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, wordpress

So, I have this menu page where a menu item, title and description are displayed.

http://restorant.aqualand.bg/?page_id=209

Right now it consists of two slideshows side by side, one for the image and one for the text. It looks kinda nice, but it's all hard-coded into the source.

I want to make it easily editable with a UI. The website is running on Wordpress, but the solution doesn't necessarily have to be a WP plug-in, as long as it's easily editable and relatively easy to implement (I'd rather not have to make a separate database and I most definitely don't want to write a whole new app just for a simple task like that).

Also, I can't use a solution where the text has to be in a picture format, because that means creating images from text and so on, and, unless it can be easily done, it's out of the question.

The final solution should be easy enough to use by someone who can't even copy/paste text properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to what you're asking requires two areas of research on your part.

First, [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). This will essentially allow you to create new content types, the default in WP being Posts, Pages, Attachments (no UI), etc. You can avoid some of the code if you prefer by using a plugin like [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/).

The second part is the Javascript. I can see you've already got some together using jQuery Cycle, and that's fine to continue using. The difference is, you'll be spitting out the elements that the slideshows use in the PHP behind your template. You'll be looking up all posts of a certain type (the new one you've created), and printing them with the correct markup for jQuery Cycle to use as a slideshow. This will involve use of [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) (specifying `post_type`).

The way the UI will come together in the dashboard when all is said and done is, you'll be using the default editor to create the content beside the picture, and the 'featured image' function build in to WordPress to upload (or select from existing media), resize, and then display your images. You could use a third field for a URL if the image and/or text is to link somewhere different for each image/text set ('slide').